# z-index dropdown menu falls behind page text

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, z-index

I'm having a problem where my CSS dropdown menus are still displaying behind all the page text. I'm using the `z-index: 9999;` on my UL item and still nothing. I added a screenshot below and you can check out [my live demo here](http://byjakewithlove.com/code/basic-responsive/).

[image: zindex ul menu bug]

I have tried adding z-index properties to most of the containers and still no luck. This small issue is killing me! I would definitely appreciate any help I can get to solve this :) thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `z-index` is correct, it appears over the content, you just forgot to add a `background-color` to your menu.

Comment: You are amazing thank you. I feel like an idiot but that was quick! I have to wait 10 mins before accepting your answer but I definitely will, considering you solved this one pretty darn fast

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely the background color, coz when hovering it covers the content behind.

also i tried it on my inspector, setting the color to white and worked.

Comment: yup me too! I guess this was an easy one to solve :) thank you very much for the feedback